# Spotfire Expression - Is there a contains function or similar?

Tags: expression, spotfire

Hi i'm new to spotfire and wondering if I can ask of some help.

I am building an expression and I have a text field called HR Entity Name. I want to only return records that contain the word "Integrated" or "IP" in them.

Is there a function for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use `~=` in the expression. `~=` basically means contains. It can also take Regular Expressions and returns true or false which can be used for Data Limiting or building other columns. It is case sensitive. For example:

`IF([HR Entity Name] ~= 'Integrated' or [HR Entity Name] ~= 'IP',TRUE,FALSE)`